# How to calculate the day between two dates using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date, datetime

I have two dates of the form:

```
Start Date: 2015-01-25 13:45:01 
End Date: 2015-01-28 02:58:01
```

Now I need to find the day between these two in the following form:

```
2015-01-25
2015-01-26
2015-01-27
2015-01-28
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i'm not idea to do this =/

Comment: Look into DatePeriod(http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) And try if you can solve it yourself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: yes but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

is not the same problem i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i just simply used [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php))

```
<?php

    $start = new DateTime("2015-01-25 13:45:01 ");
    $end = new DateTime("2015-01-28 02:58:01");
    $end = $end->modify("+1 day"); 

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($dateRange as $date)
        echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";

?>
```

Output:

```
2015-01-25
2015-01-26
2015-01-27
2015-01-28
```